# documentation for cabal-install configuration file

Tags: haskell, cabal-install

The `~/.cabal/config` stores configuration which cabal-install uses. I wanted to do some hackery on it. (Specifically, having multiple GHC versions installed, I wish to have separate documentation indexes).

I couldn't, however, find any documentation about its' syntax or variables except for what is included in default file. Is there any documentation available?

Edit: I've stated the goal above, but let me add some details: If the same package (eg. GTK) is installed in two versions of GHC they end up in the same documentation index file. I wan't that local documentation index to be separate for each GHC installation. I believe it is possible in some way using documentation directory setting, but there has to be a variable for currently used GHC version. If there isn't one there might be some workarounds available, but I won't be able to say that unless I see the documentation.

Comment: Aren't the options in the `config` file pretty much the same as the command-line flags accepted by `cabal install`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you what to do. Maybe this helps: you can install multiple ghc into different dir, the packages in .cabal dir put installed package into different sub-dirs like 'parsec-3.1.1/ghc-7.0.4/' just change 'PATH' to use different ghcs.

Comment: @Wu Xingbo: I'm assuming the goal is to use `cabal install` to install packages, but there's a single location for the config file so even with multiple copies of Cabal, there's no simple way to select a configuration.

Comment: @Wu Xinggbo: That would probably work, but I don't want to have multiple config files if possible. I already have a shell function for switching PATHs, but I would like to have it work for installed documentation as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems to work, although I've only tested it with one version of GHC:

```
documentation: True
doc-index-file: $datadir/doc/$compiler/index.html

install-dirs user
    docdir: $datadir/doc/$compiler/$pkgid
```

With the other options left at the default, this generates documentation in `.cabal/share/doc/<ghc-version>/<package-name>`, and the index in `.cabal/share/doc/<ghc-version>/index.html`.

Answer (score 3):

There appears to be very little online - not even the haddocks for the cabal-install code. So your best bet may be to puzzle it out from the source. `cabal unpack cabal-install`, or view the [cabal-install repo](http://darcs.haskell.org/cabal/cabal-install/) online. Look at `SavedConfig` in Distribution/Client/Config.hs. As an example, it imports `GlobalFlags` from Setup.hs; the individual flags, eg `globalCacheDir`, are associated with their config-file syntax (which is also the command-line syntax) in the `globalCommand` function below, `remote-repo-cache` in this case.

You should also ask dcoutts in the #haskell channel on irc.freenode.net, in case he has new docs available.