# How do I make cabal-dev build documentation by default

Tags: haskell, documentation

I frequently work in places in which I have no internet access.  I am also about to move to a place in which I will have minimal internet access.  Having documentation locally on my system is absolutely invaluable to me.

Using straight cabal, I'm able to do that just by enabling the `documentation` option in the configuration file.

How can I get the same effect with cabal-dev?  Specifically, when I install a package using cabal-dev, I want the package documentation to be generated and the index.html file for the project's documentation directory to be updated to include that package.

*update*: My question is basically a duplicate of [documentation for cabal-install configuration file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6597599/documentation-cabal-install-configuration-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit `~/.cabal/share/cabal-dev-$VERSION/admin/cabal-config.in` and set the value of the `documentation` field to `True`. The `cabal-config.in` file is a template that is used for initialising `cabal-dev/cabal.config` when creating a new sandbox.

If you want to enable documentation for an already existing `cabal-dev` sandbox, just edit `cabal-dev/cabal.config`.

---

For the users of Cabal's native sandboxes: either enable documentation in `~/.cabal/config` or create a file `cabal.config` in the same directory that your `cabal.sandbox.config` resides in with the following content:

```
documentation: True
```

Comment: That mostly does it, though it is not building the sandbox-wide index.  I was hoping for that, too.  It seems to be ignoring the doc-index-file command.

Comment: Yes, this is also a [problem for Cabal's native sandboxes](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/1337). Has to do with how the code for generating the index is implemented.